# Изменение выборки из таблицы, модель которой в зависимости “hasMany” Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel

У меня есть модель `Product` и таблица `Products`. Так же есть связанная таблица и модель `ProductImage` через `hasMany`.

```
Модель Product
    public function productimage()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
  }
```

И теперь когда я делаю выборку например
`$prod=Product::get();` А затем во вью через `@foreach` перебираю их, а когда дело доходит до картинок то использую связь: `@foreach($prod->productimage as $img)`, то выводятся все картинки. Но так же у менять есть карточка товара, для который не нужны все картинки, а только первая, для этого у меня в таблице `ProductImages` предусмотрено поле `position`, так вот, как мне её реализовать, пробовал через муттаторы, но что то не получилось:

```
Модель ProductImage
public function getCardImgAttribute() {
    return ProductImages::where('position', 1)->get();
  }
```

А во вью через `{{$img->card_img}}` выводится массив вместо одной ссылки на изображение:

```
src="/img/products/[{"path":"img_1.jpg"},{"path":"img_6.jpg"},{"path":"img_10.jpg"},{"path":"img_16.jpg"}]".
```

По идее должна выводиться ссылка для каждого элемента, а получилось что в каждом элементе 4 ссылки.

Я понимаю, что нигде не указал поле "path", которое отвечает за ссылку, я не могу понять, где я его должен указать. Что то типа `{{$img->card_img->path}}` не работает.

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getCardImgAttribute() {
    return ProductImages::where('position', 1)->get();
  }
```

У вас в этом коде допущена логическая ошибка, этот метод будет возвращать коллекцию из всех `ProductImages` у которых `position = 1` а не связаных с данным объектом.

В таком случае, вы можете сделать еще одно отношение `hasOne` в объекте `Product`
таким образом

```
   public function cardImage()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(ProductImage::class)->where('position', 1);
  }
```

Далее юзать его таким образом:

```
$product = Product::query()->first();

dd($product->cardImage->path);
```

Так же второй вариант: Суть в том, чтобы из коллекции всех картинок выбрать ту, у которой `position = 1`

```
public function cardImage()
{
  return $this->productimage->find(function(ProductImages $image) {
    return 1 === $image->position;
});
}
```

Во втором случае, не будет дополнительного запроса к базе данных. Если одновременно вам нужно использовать методы `cardImage` и `productImage` тогда лучше использовать второй вариант ибо в таком случае будет лишь один запрос к базе данных. В инном случае лучше первый, запрос к базе все равно один, но каждый ваш экземпляр `product` будет дополнительно держать в памяти еще и коллекцию из `ProductImages`, при том что нужно лишь один элемент. Но это только когда вы дойдете до оптимизации производительности.

Comment: Спасибо! Первый метод сработал, а вот на второй ругается так `Object of class Closure could not be converted to int`.